# Start up a process before I log in? (linux)

Tags: linux, startup, process, inittab

I want to start up synergy on my suse box (gnome) automatically before (preferably, or after) I log in. How do I do this? I am a major Linux newbie and I tried writing the below on the last line of /etc/inittab

```
syn:5:once:synergys --config /home/nonAdminUsername/synergy.conf
```

It didn't work. I don't see synergy process launched. How do i launch this properly?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/autostart.html), you need to add your `synergys` command to your display manager script files, which should be somewhere under `/etc`. On my Ubuntu system, they are in `/etc/gdm`.

The three files you need to edit are likely to be:

```
gdm/Init/Default
gdm/PostLogin/Default
gdm/Sessions/Default
```

Synergy needs an X server so `init` is probably not the best place to try to start it.

Comment: If you don't want to edit system config files, look for .xsession, .xinit, or similiar files in your home directory. There should be man pages for those too.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Init Script](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:How_to_Create_Your_Own_Init_Script) should tell you what you need to know.